# key is undefined react

Tags: reactjs, key, undefined

when I play this code in my localhost it tell me that "key is not defined"

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class LineTable extends React.Component{

supprimerLine = key => {
    const newLines = {...this.state.newLines};
    newLines[key] = null;
    this.setState({newLines})
};
render(){
return(
    <tr>
        <td>{this.props.details.colone1}</td>
        <td>{this.props.details.colone2}</td>
        <td>{this.props.details.colone3}</td>
        <td><button onClick={() => this.props.supprimerLine(key)}>
                                    supprimer</button></td>
    </tr>)};
static propTypes = {
    supprimerLine: PropTypes.func.isRequired};}
export default LineTable
```

I think it is because I did not import the keys but I don't know how I can import it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two point for correction.

1. `supprimerLine` is defined within the same class `LineTable`.

   So,`this.props.supprimerLine(key)` is not right way to call it.It going  to throws an error.

   The right way is `this.supprimerLine(key)` and

   in the constructor add 
   `this.supprimerLine = this.supprimerLine.bind(this)`;
2. You have not defined `key` in current context or anywhere in the class.You need to defined it first.

Answer (score 0):

Key is not defined beacause in your function context does not exists. What do you expect "key" to contain ?

```
this.props.supprimerLine(key)
```

should be undefined too because your method resides in your class and not in your props.

Comment: when I create a new line I put Date.now() as a key

Comment: in your code nothing makes your onClick function aware of the "key" string, it will be undefined.